# Selenium webdriver alerts

Tags: alerts

I am facing an issue in which my script is getting stuck in chrome because of an alert. The script is neither getting passed or failed, it's just stuck there and doesn't go forward at all due to an alert.

I have tried `Driver.switch().alert()` but no use. It seems nothing works if that alert comes up.

Could any one suggest any way to handle this kind of alert? The alert is nothing but a normal alert having an OK button and a check box which says to prevent any additional dialogues.

Could anyone please help here as this small issue has caused the script to stop at that point itself.

Thanks in advance.

Please note that I am using selenium 3.0 and it was all working fine till yesterday. Since today, I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below link it may useful for your problem.
http://seleniumsimplified.com/2013/10/faq-why-does-selenium-not-work-with-this-alert/

Comment: Thanks for the information,however my issue is of real alert only,i mean its an alert as described in the link and not a modal dialog..Still it doesn't work and the script is getting stuck,I have  handled the similar alert in the same code and it works,but when the control comes to this alerts,it gets stuck instead of being passed or failed.